# Reconstruct a saturated pulse which comes from the response of a SiPM

Tags: python, signals, data-analysis, clipping

I have a problem, i took some measurements in my laboratory course and looking at the data I found some clipped pulse. My professor asked me to reconstruct those pulse, but I have no idea how do it. Currently I'm doing data analysis with python, but I could try to work with something else. Can anyone help me?
[image: Clipped pulse]

I tried to search everything on google but I still have not find nothing